# Arcpy and multiprocessing not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, parallel-processing

I want to utilize multiprocessing within my arcpy scripts but my first test has run into a problem which I don't understand. I'm running the script in the python window:

```py
import arcpy
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x
pool = Pool(processes=4)
print pool.map(f,[1,2,3,4])
```

As soon as I assign the processes, ArcMap open four new instances and the script does not print the values of x as expected (the above code is from an example I found). The new instances of ArcMap initialize but then close with the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a setting/patch I've ignored?
I'm using ArcMap Desktop 10.0 SP5 build 4400 and I have also tried the code on 10.3.1.4959.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiprocessing is trying to use ArcMap.exe instead of python.exe to run the child processes.

Either disable running the script 'in process' or use `multiprocessing.set_executable(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'python.exe'))`

Note: don't use `sys.executable` to get the path to python.exe if running in-process as it will be pointing to ArcMap.exe, use `sys.exec_prefix` instead:

```
>>> import os, sys
>>> print sys.executable
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin\arcmap.exe
>>> print os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'python.exe')
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe
```

Comment: I have altered my script to include this redirect but it now hangs ArcMap. I work have expected some feedback in the python window about worker processes and results but I get nothing. ArcMap just becomes unresponsive.